# Back button behaviour issue

Tags: android

Helping to create an app, very new to using android studio and as a programmer. Just wondering if anyone could help with this current issue. 
This is a secure server communication app.

On the app there is a back button on the conversation screen which should take you back to the conversation thread. Once you kill the app on your phone and open a message on the app through a notification it takes you directly to the conversation screen, but as you hit the back button instead of going back to the conversation thread it takes you off the app completely which is not what we want.

Can someone please tell me whereabouts I should go to fix this problem and the code to do so. 
Thank you

Comment: Provide your code for onBackPressed and/or your Back button onClick

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(setIntent);
    }

Comment: @nsamad400 He is talking about a backbutton **on the conversation screen** so that's a normal button, and **not** the device it's backbutton, and please **don't** put code like that in the comment section.

Comment: @nsamad400 didn't you tried my solution given in answer

Comment: Sorry apologies, on the conversation activity I am finding no indication of a backbutton, or Onbackpressed.

Answer (score 0):

It because once you open activity from the notification will be root activity. and hitting back button just close the app.

You need to check for the root activity. Try this method [isTaskRoot()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot()).

Once you open activity initial check for that the activity is root or not. If it is root then call `startActivity()` else if not root call back functionality.

So for example:

```
YourBackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isTaskRoot()){          //Check if it is your root activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Current_class.this,Conversation_thread.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            finish(); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry apologies, on the conversation activity I am finding no indication of a backbutton, or Onbackpressed.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onBackPressed() {


 //start your conversation thread class here. something like this

  Intent intent=new Intetn(Current_class.this,Conversation_thread.class);
  startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Hope this helps you!.